# how to create NFT that can't be sold with smart contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, polygon

I want to write a custom smart contract that prevents the owner of the NFT to sell it. I'm thinking of using a boolean tag in the contract and use that in a "required" statement and hook that into the transfer function. Will that be enough to stop it from being listed and sold on any nft marketplace?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721, Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
    bool transferable = false;
    bool public saleIsActive = true;

    constructor() ERC721("name", "symbol") {}

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal override whenNotPaused {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal override {
        require(transferable == true, "token transfer/resale is not allowed");
        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work, it's just strange. Btw you can just do require(transferable) instead of trasnferable ==.

Comment: The variable `transferable` is never modified, it shouldn't be needed if using `Pausable`. It seems odd overriding `_transfer` but not calling `super._transfer()`, is there some reason to do that?